# Insert std::string and shared pointer to object in map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, singleton

I'm using singleton design pattern (I can't use the copy constructor).

I have a:

- Obj.hpp and Obj.cpp file
- House.hpp and House.cpp file

The Obj class contains a map of Houses, where I can search for a house using a string.
I can't even compile my Obj.cpp file, don't know why... :(

The error is the following:

> error C2676: binary '<' : 'const std::string' does not define this
>   operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined
>   operator

*[Obj.hpp file]*

```
#include "house.hpp"

class Obj
{
public:
    Obj();
    virtual ~Obj();
private:
    Obj(const Obj& copy);
    Obj& operator=(const Obj& assign);

    typedef std::map<const std::string, std::shared_ptr<House> > myHouseMap;

    myHouseMap _myHouseMap;

    void InitObj ();
}
```

*[Obj.cpp file]*

```
#include <map.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Obj.hpp"

Obj::Obj()
{
    InitObj ();
}

void Obj::InitObj ()
{
    /* ERROR ON THIS LINE BELLOW */
    _myHouseMap.insert(std::pair<const std::string, std::shared_ptr<House>>("apartment", new House("apartment")));

}
```

*[House.hpp file]*

```
class House
{
public:

    House(const char* name);
    virtual ~House();

private:
    House(const House& copy);
    House& operator=(const House& assign);
};
```

Comment: The line seems fine unless your compiler is not 100% C++11 in which case it might need a space between the two >>.

Comment: Oh and your includes should be <map> and <string> without the .h

Comment: Your key type should not be `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which version of Visual Studio you are using, but at least Visual Studio 2013 seems fine with this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class House
{
public:

    House(const char* name);
    virtual ~House();

private:
    House(const House& copy)
    {
    }
    House& operator=(const House& assign)
    {
    }
};

class Obj
{
public:
    Obj()
    {
        InitObj();
    }
    virtual ~Obj();
private:
    Obj(const Obj& copy);
    Obj& operator=(const Obj& assign);

    typedef std::map<const std::string, std::shared_ptr<House> > myHouseMap;

    myHouseMap _myHouseMap;

    void InitObj()
    {
        // Use std::make_shared to create a new std::shared_ptr
        _myHouseMap.insert(std::pair<const std::string, std::shared_ptr<House>>("apartment", std::make_shared<House>("apartment")));
    }
};
```

The issue is that the pair constructor expects a `std::shared_ptr` not a raw pointer.

Comment: Thank you all:) Was indeed a missing a confusion between shared_ptr and raw pointers! :)

Comment: @waas1919 I can understand that, since `std::shared_ptr` has a constructor that takes a raw pointer but the `std::pair` constructor wants the actual type of the pair.